# RuntimeWarning from Fsolve

Tags: optimization, scipy, runtime, warnings

I am using scipy.optimize.fsolve to find the roots of a function. The problem is that sometimes I get this warning: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations.

I want to solve this problem by 2 methods:

1) increasing number of iterations maybe can solve the problem. But I do not know how can I do this.

2) If the program gets this warning try to use another function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1) It will probably not help increasing the number of iterations, because as the warning is saying, the solution isn't improving very much for each iteration. But you can give the maximum number of evaluations allowed of the given function using the `maxfev` argument.

2) You could try some the other SciPy optimisation methods, but you could run in the same problem with all of them.

A thing you could try, is to re-run the optimisation with a new starting point each time you get the warning. You could let the code do this a given number of times until it doesn't receive the warning, or it has tried too often. The starting point for the optimisation is given by `x0`. You can read the full documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).